# Why is graphite solid but water liquid?

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds

$\ce{H2O}$ has primary covalent and secondary hydrogen bonds (hence it is liquid). Graphite has primary covalent and secondary Van der Waals bonds. Still, graphite is a solid. Why is this so?

Comment: Do you know how many atoms are there in a water molecule?

Comment: Truthfully water and graphite are so different that it makes no sense to be trying to compare them.

Comment: Water can also be solid, or a gas. This depends on so much more than just the kind of bonding.

Comment: Have you seen the structure of graphite?

Answer (score 4):

**Bonding types are not a good guide to the form of a compound: you also need to know the structure**

The types of bonding involved in a compound tell you something about what form it will take. But not very much. The structure of the compound matters far more.

Water is a small molecule with only three covalently bonded atoms in it. They mystery is why isn't it a gas (the structurally similar but heavier hydrogen sulphide is a gas at normal conditions!). The strong hydrogen bonds explain why it is a liquid: they stick the molecules together more tightly than the much weaker inter molecular bonds in the sulphide).

Graphite isn't a small molecule: it is a nearly-infinite array of hexagonal sheets of carbon atoms. These sheets are held together by van Der Waals forces. The components of graphite are not small molecules but those large sheets which is why it is not a liquid under normal conditions (few substances made of near-infinite arrays of atoms are). But the relatively weak bonds holding the extended sheets together do have an impact on the nature of graphite: the sheets can move relative to each other easily. This makes graphite behave enough like a liquid *in some spatial directions* that it is sometimes used as a lubricant.

So the very different properties of water and graphite can be understood only by knowing *both* the sorts of bonds involved *and* the structure of the components making up the compounds.